# 301 Редирект перенаправить страницу А на Б

Tags: редирект, .htaccess

Ребят, помогите сделать 301 Редирект через файл .htaccess

Нужно страницы `site.ru/?do=yasitemap` и `site.ru/index.php?do=yasitemap` перенаправить на `site.ru/yasitemap/`

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как реализовать?

Comment: Что конкретно непонятно из документации по mod_rewrite и примеров оттуда же?

Comment: Пробовал код, не работает
RewriteRule index.php?do=yasitemap ^yasitemap/ [R=301,L]

Comment: Так может всё-таки почитать документацию по mod_rewrite? Она небольшая, а раздел раздел [RewriteQueryString][1] вообще крохотный.


  [1]: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} yasitemap
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yasitemap/ [R=301,L]
Так тоже не помогает, редиректит на site.ru/yasitemap/?do=yasitemap

Comment: Вы забыли прочитать до конца второе предложение из двух в разделе "Rewriting For Certain Query Strings" :-)